# Searching for special characters with RegEx

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string looking as follows:

> ['(18|H)', '(27|V)', '(29|*)']

I want to filter all the single character after the between | and ). I could filter out the characters H and V with the following regex, which was pretty easy for a beginner: `([A-Z])`
Now i got the problem that i cannot filter out the `'*'`, because of the use of the star in the regex. I tried to use the square brackets and the backlash to solve this problem, but as you can see, it didn't work.

Has someone an idea how can solve this matter? Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you used? Is that a string or list in fact?

Comment: You can try looking at groups, and match the pattern of "|.)" where . is the wildcard character

Comment: use escape character '\' , in your case `\*`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = ['(18|H)', '(27|V)', '(29|*)']
print([re.search(r"\|(.*)\)", i).group(1) for i in data])
```

**Output:**

```
['H', 'V', '*']
```

Comment: good approach, but i need the characters after the numbers (after the |)

Comment: in this case: ['H','V', '*']

Comment: sorry misunderstood your question.....`print([re.search(r"\|(.*)\)", i).group(1) for i in data])`

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?<=\|).(?=\))`

Explanation:

`(?<=\|)` - positive lookbehind: assert what preceds is `\|`, which matches `|` literally

`.` - match any character

`(?=\))` - positive lookahead: assert what follows is `\)`, which matches `)` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AyjNSQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

"Filter all" is a little confusing - not sure if you want to filter it OUT or keep JUST those in... Assuming you want JUST the single characters that come after the `|` and before the `)` you want something like this:

```
\|(.)\)
```

That will put whatever character is between the `|` and the `)` into your `$1`.

Even if I'm mis-reading your question, I think this will get you going in the right direction - just use dot (.) to represent that single character and escape the special characters `|` and `)`.

I'm assuming you know how to use the `$1` (or `\1`, depending on the flavor of regex you are using - I haven't used Python in quite some time and don't remember the exact syntax)